# Use Google Apps Script function in manifest (JSON) - Gmail Addon

Tags: google-apps-script, google-workspace-add-ons

I would like to translate the Universal Actions text in the add-on I develop. I have a Google Apps Script function that take a text and return the traduction. Do you know a way to use a Google Apps Script / JavaScript function in a JSON manifest?

The universal action :

```
"universalActions": [
      {
        "text": "Account",
        "runFunction": "goToAccount"
      }
    ]
```

My Google Apps Script function:

```
function translate(text) {
  var language = CacheService.getUserCache().get('language');
  return LanguageApp.translate(text, "", language);
}
```

Comment: Where is this JSON Manifest, you speak of?

Comment: This is the Apps Script project manifest written in JSON that define details about the Gmail add-on project, this is the main "appsscript.json" file.

Comment: It's possible for a script through [tag:google-apps-script-api] , but add-ons - I'm not so sure

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not think it's possible for now ...