# How to internationalize a google workspace addon?

Tags: google-apps-script, internationalization, manifest, google-workspace-add-ons

I wrote a Gmail addon which is using different languages.

But I cannot manage to translate the title in the sidebar nor the hover text of the icon. See yellow marks in screenshot.

[image: yellow marks show not translateble items]

At first I thought the text is coming from the marketplace but it seems to be from manifest file *appsscript.json*.

```
"addOns": {
    "common": {
        "name": "Translate",
…
```

as described here: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/manifest/addons

None of the documentations provide an answer, because variables seem not to work in the manifest file:

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/how-tos/access-user-locale
- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/concepts/event-objects#common_event_object
- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/session#getactiveuserlocale

I was looking around for solutions (i18n, translation, localisation, …), e.g.

- [Use Google Apps Script function in manifest (JSON) - Gmail Addon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53173099/use-google-apps-script-function-in-manifest-json-gmail-addon/74708162?noredirect=1#comment131856407_74708162) --> question on file but different part
- [How to internationalize universalActions label in a Google Workspace Add-On](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74296535/how-to-internationalize-universalactions-label-in-a-google-workspace-add-on/74401125#74401125) --> solution I found for question above but not usable for name
- [Localizing Google Add-ons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37478491/localizing-google-add-ons) --> solution is for Chrome not Workspace Addons
- [Can I use getActiveUserLocale() in onOpen(e) of a published Add-on?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62822170/can-i-use-getactiveuserlocale-in-onopene-of-a-published-add-on) --> not usable in manifest

but could not find a solution.

---

I can support different languages in the store and in the addon but not in manifest file?

Does anyone have an idea or workaround?

Comment: This looks to be a repost of an closed as duplicate question. Reposting isn't allowed, instead edit the original question.

Answer (score -1):

According to the [Add-on manifest documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/manifest/addons#common), the mentioned manifest field is meant to store your add-on name.

> name: Required. The name of the add-on shown in the toolbar.

Since this field is meant for the name of your add-on, it sounds like expected behavior not being able to update it on runtime.

Here is an open [Feature Request ticket](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/213924415) with Google to add support for this functionality.

Comment: The add-on manifest could hold more things that only the add-on name.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear, but I meant that the `addOns.common.name` value (in the manifest file) changes the referred sidebar header. And this field is meant to hold the Add-on name as documented.